# How to start QuickTime recording at command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-lion, quicktime

How to start QuickTime video recording on a MacBook at the command line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) Create a Applescript by AppleScript Editor and save it (e.g. QTRecord.scpt):

```
 tell application "QuickTime Player"
     activate
     start (new movie recording)
 end tell
```

2) Open Terminal and run the script in command line:

```
 osascript QTRecord.scpt
```

Or the whole thing as an one-liner:

```
 osascript -e 'tell application "QuickTime Player" to activate' -e 'tell application "QuickTime Player" to start (new movie recording)'
```

Comment: How do you know those parameters ? Apple script editor 'Record' function, don't provide that... @ohho

Comment: @CodeFarmer Using Xcode, open QuickTImePlayerX.sdef, located Inside the Contents folder of the Quicktime Player X package.

Comment: Another way to check the commands in a more readable way is to open the .app bundle in **Script Editor** using **File → Open Dictionary...**

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site,](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=64614) it can be done using Applescript

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"

    set nr to (new movie recording)
    set nr to start recording true
    delay 10
    set nr to stop recording true
end tell
```

So it interacts with Quick-time. There are no direct commands with QuickTime.

Comment: Compiling the above code gives a syntax error: `Expected end of line, etc. but found “true”.`

Answer (score 0):

To start a QuickTime recording at the command line on a Mac, you can use the osascript command to execute AppleScript code. Here's an example script that you can use:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    start (new movie recording)
    delay 1 -- Optional delay to give QuickTime time to start recording
end tell
```

To execute this AppleScript code from the command line, you can create a file with a .scpt extension, for example, start_recording.scpt, and then run the following command in the terminal:

```
osascript /path/to/start_recording.scpt
```

This will launch QuickTime Player, start a new movie recording, and begin recording the screen or webcam, in [sinuano noche game](https://sinuanonoche.org/) players select a three-digit number ranging from 000 to 999 and can choose from various bet types. Depending on your QuickTime settings.